# Acquire exclusive ownership of a core and disabling interrupts on it with C++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark a piece of C++11 code on a multicore CPU(Intel core i5). It is desirable to reduce the noise of context switching, process scheduling, etc. Thus, I want to acquire exclusive ownership of one core and disabling any interrupts on it.

**How can I do it with C++ and G++ compiler?**

The paper [benchmarking-code-execution](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf) uses   `preempt_disable();` and `raw_local_irq_save(flags);` to accomplish that goal. However, those two functions are from linux kernel headers and the paper wrote a linux kernel module to call them.

Answer (score 3):

This is availble in recent kernels, the feature is called "tickless" or "NOHZ" mode. Still rather experimental/rough around the edges though. See [this LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/549580/) for more information.